# CSS animations not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, css-animations

I have used the CSS animation `fadeInLeft` from [Click here](http://daneden.me/animate/) however I have come to notice since I have added jQuery to the transition.

```
$('#one').click(function(){
    $('#two-bck').removeClass('animated');
    $('#three-bck').removeClass('animated');
    $('#four-bck').removeClass('animated');
    $('#one-bck').addClass('animated');
});
```

[click here to see the full code](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/kJ2UA/3/)

The transition doesn't work in Firefox even though I have added prefixes. Does anyone know how I can work around this problem?

Comment: Your css is not valid. Sometimes browsers act weird because of that. [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). Edit: does your console show any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Your code from animate.css is off somehow, I simply replaced your animation CSS with the full minified version of animate.css and hey presto it works. http://jsfiddle.net/kJ2UA/14/

You can create a custom build with only your fadeInLeft animation and include that on the page somewhere if you don't want to have to include the full stylesheet.

Also, you should clean up your jQuery a bit (off topic), e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.proBtn').on('click', function(){
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $('li a').removeClass('blue');
        // Remove anything previously animated
        $('.animated').removeClass('animated');
        // Use current ID to select appropriate box
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-bck').addClass('animated');
        $(this).parent("li").addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('blue');
    });
});
```